# Turn each word into a variable with python

Tags: python

I have a text which I need to delete the first two words and store the numbers into a variable.

I am trying to split the words and then create a loop to store each word in a variable.

My text is: "ABA BLLO 70000000 12-2022"

So I am trying to store the numbers, which can alternate depending on the data set and create a variable for each of them.

```
text = "ABA BLLO 70000000 12-2022"

a = text.strip().strip("")
for a in text:
    print(a)
```

So I would have three variables:

```
number = 70000000 
month = 12
year = 2022
```

Comment: The code you've given doesn't come close to doing what you want to do. I think you'd be better-served by reading some tutorials

Comment: do you know which type of tutorial I should look for to solve my issue?

Comment: I don't know one off the top of my head sorry, but this is relatively fundamental stuff for the language

Answer (score 0):

After using something like

```
tempSplit = text.split()
```

You're going to get a list class.

```
result = [s for s in tempSplit if s.isdigit()]
```

And with that you can get int objects but problem with this last fourth element is a Date object you have to use another function for that.

As @roganjosh suggested with the comment you should check other tutorials to find out about different functions. Like for this instance maybe you can try split function then learn how to get only numbers from a list.

To get dates

```
month = tempSplit[3].split("-")[0]
year = tempSplit[3].split("-")[1]
```

Comment: Yeah you're right about that and still mine doesn't answer the question
And for this code to work input of dates can't change positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split function to split the string on white-spaces and convert all the splitted strings into a list. Then you can slice the array to remove the first two elements and destructure the remaining array into variables.

```py
text = "ABA BLLO 70000000 12-2022"
x,y = text.split()[2:]

print(x,y)
```

NOTE : This would work only if there's a fixed format for the input string.

Answer (score 0):

If i get your point right, then try to check this code:

```
text = "ABA BLLO 70000000 12-2022"

counter = 0
word = []
number = []
for a in text.split(" "):
    if counter <= 1:
      word.append(a)
    else:
      number.append(a) 
    counter += 1
print(word)
print(number)
```

The output will be

```
['ABA', 'BLLO']
['70000000', '12-2022']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm catching your drift but here's my answer:

```
new_text = text.split(" ")

for i in range(2, len(new_text)):
    if i == 2:
        number = new_text[i]
    else:
        month = new_text[i].split("-")[0]
        year = new_text[i].split("-")[1]

print(f"Number: {number}\nMonth: {month}\nYear: {year}")
```